# How make a window with QT 6,0?

Tags: qt

Hi to everyone Im beguinner with QT 6.0 Im started to practice with but I get this error message

```
C:\Users\blabla\Documents\Programming\VentanaPrincipal\main.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QWidgetC1EPS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
CMakeFiles/VentanaPrincipal.dir/main.cpp.obj: In function `main':
C:/Users/blabla/Documents/Programming/VentanaPrincipal/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QWidgetC1EPS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
```

literally this is the code what I made and As well I'm saw at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-toplevel-example.html

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;

    window.resize(320,240);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: show your .pro...

Comment: there isn't .pro because I'm using CMake

Comment: Undefined reference is generally a *linker* error, not a compiler one, hence probably has nothing to do with your code. More likely, you just need to ensure you're linking with the Qt stuff. And, since you're using CMake, you should probably show us your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(VentanaPrincipal LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(VentanaPrincipal
  main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(VentanaPrincipal Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)

Comment: Okay, `Qt5::Core` *may* be enough for `QCoreApplication` but I'm pretty certain any widgets will also need `Qt5::Widgets` (in the `target_link_libraries` stanza).

Comment: @EricM.M.C change to `target_link_libraries(VentanaPrincipal Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets) `

Comment: hummm ok let me see

Comment: now i got theese messages error 

C:\Users\blabla\Documents\Programming\VentanaPrincipal\CMakeLists.txt:17: error: Target "VentanaPrincipal" links to target "Qt6::Coret" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
 C:\Users\blabla\Documents\Programming\VentanaPrincipal\CMakeLists.txt:17: error: Target "VentanaPrincipal" links to target "6::Widgets" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: @EricM.M.C Also see the official docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html

Comment: Eric, the error sections in your most recent comment, `Qt6::Coret` (superfluous `t` suffix) and `6::Widgets` (missing `Qt` prefix), point to problems in the CMakeLists.txt file. I'd say you've most likely entered something like `Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Coret ${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets`. It needs to be `Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets` (see my answer for full details).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to your question, your `CMakeLists.txt` file has this for the library requirements:

```
 target_link_libraries(VentanaPrincipal Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)
```

While `core` brings in a large chunk of `Qt`, it does not bring in *everything.* In particular, if you want to use widgets, you'll need `Qt*::Widgets` as well.

---

A good way to ensure you have everything you need is to look at the documentation for the classes you wish to use. For example, the [QWidget documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) (for Qt5, which is what I use) has this in the table at the top:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| Header:   | #include <QWidget> |
+-----------+--------------------+
| qmake:    | QT += widgets      |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

That means you need to include the `QWidget` header file *and* link with the `widgets` library. Were you using `qmake`, that would simply involve putting that exact line `QT += widgets` into your project file.

The equivalent in `cmake` would result in the following changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
target_link_libraries(VentanaPrincipal
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
)
```

---

The [equivalent Qt6 documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html) is even better since it now shows the `cmake` stuff as well, meaning you don't need to think about translating the `qmake` variant:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Header:   | #include <QWidget>                                   |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| CMake:    | find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)        |
|           | target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets) |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| qmake:    | QT += widgets                                        |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The OP is using Qt6 so he should add `Qt6::Widgets` or better `Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets` to support both versions

Comment: @eyllanesc: good point, I've been using Qt5 for so long, it's now just a muscle memory when typing.  Adjusted to suit question.

Comment: In the Qt6 docs it indicates how this module should be added in cmake: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(VentanaPrincipal LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(VentanaPrincipal
  main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(VentanaPrincipal Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt6::Widgets)

Comment: I can solve it thank you so much to everyone who tries to help me :)

Comment: Glad we could help. @Eric. Try to be consistent in naming though (use `Qt6` or `Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}`, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

How about using QApplicacion instead of QCoreApplication?

`QApplication a(argc, argv);`

You also don't need cmake. You should create simple project, and use qmake to generate makefile.

Chcek this thread: [Simple Qt program builds but doesn't show output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340005/simple-qt-program-builds-but-doesnt-show-output).

Comment: Well, even [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-toplevel-example.html) OP provided and which I just tested and it works, uses QApplication.